# Sort dict by a dict value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a `dict`'s value where the value is a `dict` where the value is a `list` of two integers. I'm trying to sort the rows in the inner `dict` by the first integer of the `list`.

This is the value of the `dict`:

```
{'EQUITY': {'CA': [15, 20], 'US': [25, 30]}, ... }
```

Here, the 'US' row should come before the 'CA' row after sorting.

This is what I'm currently trying:

`dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][ ?? ], reverse=True))`

**how should I index into the inner dict from here ??**

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: After the edit, are you trying to sort the outer dict or inner dict? You've got conflicting info.

Comment: sorry I incorrectly explained my question and I have edited it. Also, I am using this 'sorting' to make the user see the more important (larger integer) rows before the smaller ones.

Comment: In your reworded question, why would `US` come before `CA`? (25 > 15)

Comment: @wjandrea I only want to reorder the inner dict items (US and CA)

Comment: @Orozco Cause it's reversed sort. Notice the `reverse=True`.

Comment: @Orozco with reverse=True, US would come before CA. Even though in this case it isn't needed to sort these values, in the future, the rows could look more like: **US:25, CA:15, MX: 22**

Comment: @Rohan The question still says "I'm trying to sort a dict where the value is a dict ...", and seems to imply that `data` is the outer dict, which is not what you're trying to sort. Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). You should have all these details hammered out before posting. See also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4518341), though some of the answers are a bit extreme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Try the following, which uses dict comprehension and `sorted` with `key` parameter:

```py
dct = {'EQUITY': {'CA': [15, 20], 'US': [25, 30]}, 'FUTURE': {'CA': [5, 5], 'US': [10, 2]}}

output = {k: dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0], reverse=True)) for k, d in dct.items()}

print(output)
# {'EQUITY': {'US': [25, 30], 'CA': [15, 20]}, 'FUTURE': {'US': [10, 2], 'CA': [5, 5]}}
```

Here, each `item` of `d.items()` would be a tuple like `('CA', [15, 20])`. Therefore, to sort by `15`, you need `item[1][0]`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't occur to me that I had to iterate through the outer dict and then use the sorting method on the inner one.